# Call ajax to check a status then add a css class

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery to cycle through a list of events and check a users attendance status. A simple ajax call using the rel value for event_id results in a result of either "0" or "1".

If the attendance is positive (1) then I want to add a class of .selected to the link.

My calls seem to work and I can bring the results up in an alert, but for some reason the class isn't being added when I try that.

Here is my HTML:

```
<a class="icon attend tip" href="#" title="RSVP Your Attendance" rel="59"></a>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
    $('a.attend').each(function(index) {

        $.ajax({
          url: '<?php echo site_url('ajax/event_attendance_status') ?>/' + $(this).attr('rel'),
          success: function(data) {         
            if (data == '1') {
                $(this).addClass('selected');
            };
          }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Can we see a live version to debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're inside the callback function the context of the function differs from when you setup the request. Therefore, the **this** object refers to something else (in this case I think it's the `XMLHttpRequest` object.)

There are two ways of doing this. You could either save the `this` object in another variable, and then use that variable to access the element, like so:

```
var element = $(this);
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo site_url('ajax/event_attendance_status') ?>/' + $(this).attr('rel'),
    success: function(data) {         
        if (data == '1') {
            $(element).addClass('selected');
        };
    }
});
```

An alternative, and frankly nicer and more elegant solution is to use the [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) method to ensure the callback gets fired in the correct context.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo site_url('ajax/event_attendance_status') ?>/' + $(this).attr('rel'),
    success: jQuery.proxy(function(data) {         
        if (data == '1') {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }, this);
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 For solving context issue. Could also be done by adding `context: this` to the settings object that is passed to the ajax call. Do you have any idea what is going on with the url? That's server-side code.

Comment: Thank you! I'd forgotten about `context: this`. It looks to be a piece of PHP code calling the CodeIgniter helper site URL. Obviously the author is using this to output the URL.

Comment: OK, I get it. I was was assuming this to be a snippet of "pure" JavaScript when in reality it is a snippet of the PHP template that generates the JavasScript. Thanks.